# Problems installing Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, canopy

I was having trouble installing Python 2.7 on my system and initially I thought it was because I had Python 3.3 installed first (which was working fine).

So, I removed Python 3 and started a fresh installation of Python 2.7.8. Though it installs without any problem, it refuses to run. If I try to open IDLE from Start in Windows nothing happens. When I go to cmd and type:

```
C:\Python27> .\python.exe
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

How can I get Python to install properly?

P.S. I also have an academic license for Enthought Canopy. The problem persists with that too. It installs without any error, but just refuses to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Not clear if you tried to start Canopy itself, which is the final step in installation setup, as described in User Guide: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_windows.html

2) If Canopy itself won't start, check this article:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22508619-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything

3) The Canopy GU application does everything that IDLE does, and more, so I would recommend using it once you get it running.

Comment: One of the potential problems mentioned in the Enthought support is that a previous installation of python may have set the path incorrectly. That was indeed my problem. Correcting it solved both issues.